# Sorting specific woocommerce categories based on attributes

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, filter, categories

I'm trying to sort some specific categories based on product attributes.

I have tried many alternatives, and I cant figure it out.

```
function custom_category_archive_sorting( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $category_slug = $query->get_queried_object()->slug;

        $custom_sorted_categories = array(
            'handmade',
            'ancient-collection',
            'opal',
            'meander',
            'semiprecious-stones',
        );

        if ( in_array( $category_slug, $custom_sorted_categories ) ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'pa_category' );

            $terms_order = array(
                'rings',
                'bracelets',
                'earrings',
                'necklaces',
                'pendants',
                'chains',
            );

            $tax_query = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category_slug,
                ),
            );

            $query->set( 'meta_value', $terms_order );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_category_archive_sorting' );
```

What I get when I try to visit the specific categories is: **No products were found that match your selection.**